# How to call the functions of Ethereum Smart Contract from Android/iOS application?

Tags: solidity, nodejs, vyper

I've been learning solidity & viper for some time now but i am wondering if it's possible to call the functions/methods of a smart contract (already deployed on Ethereum Network) from an Android/iOS application.
If it is, then how do we go about doing it?

I found [this](https://github.com/Imaginea/lms) project on GitHub, which is creating APIs for the Smart Contract. Once the code is deployed on the server those APIs can be called from Android/iOS. But, in the project we are using TestRPC for deploying the Smart Contract. So, what i don't understand is how can it communicating with the Smart Contract which is already deployed on the Ethereum Network?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the "client" to interact with Ethereum, one needs "web3" library.

Most popular ones are `web3.js` and `web3.py` That is why people prefer to create API using either node or python.

There are other benefits of APIs as well. e.g. You most likely need some sort of API for your android app to talk to the server anyway. Might as well use the same to "connect" to ethereum.

Having said that, have a look at [this](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) project - which provides web3 interface for java.